# UWP Application UI fails to function in Release mode but fine in Debug mode

Tags: uwp

I am a bit stuck now with a UWP app that works fine in DEBUG mode but when compiled for Release mode the UI fails to function.  Buttons are always disabled and the bindings are not functional so basically nothing works.

How is this even possible - I have no idea where to begin looking.

Comment: Would you please share the code that you are using? And please also try the code in a new project to see if this issue happens for every project.

Comment: Upgraded to .net 4.8 (from 4.7) and that seems to have fixed things !